# How to copy entire fields into a python list

Tags: python, arcpy, fields-attributes, list

I'am trying to find a way to copy entire fields(columns) in a feature class attribute table as lists inside a master list (python).

To illustrate it, consider the table below:

[image]

So the list should look something like this:

```
talukas = [[26190, 26191, 26192, 26193, 26194, 26195, ...], 
   [Tharad, Vadgam, Vav, Amod, Ankleshwar, Bharuch, ...],
    [None, None, None, None, None, Ahmedabad Ciy, ...] ]
```

I was trying this,

```
    features = [[row.getValue(f) for f in fields] for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)]
```

but this gives the entire row values in sub-list and not column value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close!

`features = [[row.getValue (field.name) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor (fc)] for field in arcpy.ListFields (fc)]`

With `da`:

`features = [[r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc, field.name)] for field in arcpy.ListFields (fc)]`

Comment: Thanks @Emil , that kind of works. But in "row.getValue(field.name)" , it says object has no attribute 'name'.  COuld you also show me how to do it with data access module - arcpy.da.

Comment: Hmm, strange. But since it looks like you have your fields listed in variable `fields` already: `[[row.getValue (f) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor (fc)] for f in fields]`

Comment: yes they were listed.  but I also tried using arcpy.ListFields.

Answer (score 2):

```
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
theTable=arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(fc,fields)
```

Comment: thanks felixIP for your input. however, do you know what could be the reason for ,  TypeError: long() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: It won't work with Null values

Comment: ok. perhaps assigning some dummy value might work with argument : null_value = "NA".

Comment: It will work, this is what I'd do anyway